# What is the meaning? -- 誰かいないのか

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-の, questions, particle-か

I need your help.

"誰かいないのか"

As far as I understand it, this translates to something like, "I want to know, if there somebody, who is available now"

The questions are:

1. Is the translation ok?
2. Could you explain the grammar of this sentence? I was trying to find out about "inai no ka" but didn't manage to do it :(

I really count on you guys!

Thank you!

P.S. yes, I'm a newbie

Comment: The preceding context may help with a more precise translation.

Answer (score 2):

「誰かいないのか」most likely means "Is anyone here?" without further context. It's the kind of thing you'd say if you walked into an empty room expecting to find someone, but there was no one there.

いないのか is just a questioning form of いない. It's very casual but has a bit of urgency to it. It's kind of like saying "Isn't there someone here?!" or "Anybody home?!"

Comment: That's true, which is why I prefaced my answer with "...without further context..." 

Given that there are many possibilities, why not provide an answer that expands upon mine and provides more examples and their appropriate contexts? Simply saying my answer is incomplete doesn't help anyone reading this post to learn, much less answer the original poster's question.